# how to fit an ImageView inside a CardView

Tags: android

I have a fixed size `CardView`, and I need to fill it with an `ImageView`, this is how the code looks so far:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card1x"


        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/futourImage"

            android:src="@drawable/futourfie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And in order to fit it, tried :

```
ImageView futour = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.futourImage);
futour.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

But doesn't seems to solve the problem, looking for an effective solution! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried **android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"** for ImageView?

Comment: tried now, no difference, is there any way to stretch things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fixed it** by changing :

```
ImageView image_id = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageID);
image_id.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

and setting :

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for the `ImageView`

Answer (score -1):

Have a layout like relative layout as the main child of the CardView and then have the ImageView the child view of the layout. Then set the ImageView's width and height to match_parent.

You could also alternatively have a framelayout as the main child of the CardView and set its background to the image. Will stretch it up to fill the Card.